# Color output of last command in terminal

Tags: bash, macos, shell, unix, awk

When I am reading the output of a bash command in terminal on mac, I find it hard to locate where the output of the command starts. I would like to color the output of the latest command in red and and then when I run a new command, have only the output of that command be red while the output of previous commands is black.

Edit:

As an example,

```
echo hi
hi <- should be red
```

then when I enter another command

```
echo hi
hi <- should be black
echo 'hi there'
hi there <- should be red
```

Comment: A common technique is to add color to your prompt.  Eg, at the beginning of PS1, include `\033[01;31m` to make your prompt red, then put `\033[01;32m` at the end of PS1 to convert text to green.  You will also want to add `\[` and `\]` brackets around the color commands so that bash can properly compute the length of the prompt and position the cursor in the correct place.

Comment: just a question: why is this question bad? I'm asking how to do something in mac terminal. It is a very specific item and has a specific answer. It is programming related.

Comment: It doesn't follow the rules at [ask] including providing a [mcve]. I personally cannot parse the sentence `I would like to color the output of the last command in red and and then when I run a new command, have the rest of the output be recolored to black and the new latest output be red`. What does "the rest" mean? Is it the same as "the new latest" or something else? Are you trying to run 2 commands simultaneously in the background with interleaved different color output from each or do something else? A [mcve] would be enormously useful.

Comment: Then ask for an example and don't downvote. I can't improve the question if you just click the down arrow. I would assume that "the rest" would pretty obviously be output from previous commands.

Comment: I didn't downvote, I replied to your question asking what was wrong with your question and in that reply I did ask for an example. No it was not obvious at all. So you want to run a command and have it's output appear on your screen in red, then run a second command and have the output of the previous command that's currently being displayed in red turn to black and and have the output of the new command displayed in red? I certainly would never have thought THAT was what you were asking for! Good luck...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a shell function to do that:

```
xtrace() {
  awk '
  BEGIN {
    d = "\47"; printf "\33[36m"
    while (++q < ARGC) {
      x = split(ARGV[q], y, d); y[1]
      for (z in y) {
        printf "%s%s", !x || y[z] ~ "[^[:alnum:]%+,./:=@_-]" ? d y[z] d : y[z],
        z < x ? "\\" d : ""
      }
      printf q == ARGC - 1 ? "\33[m\n" : FS
    }
  }
  ' "$@"
  "$@"
}
```

Put this in your ~/.profile or similar, then run like this:

```
$ xtrace echo alfa 'bravo charlie'
echo alfa 'bravo charlie'
alfa bravo charlie
```

The command will be printed in blue, followed by the output of the command
printed normally.

> [image: colored output]

[Source](//github.com/svnpenn/stdlib/blob/d0d3b5a/libstd.sh#L59-L76)

Answer (score 1):

It's not *exactly* what you asked, but Terminal has a feature called "Marks". By default, it automatically marks each command line in the window. The marks appear as faint square brackets ([, ]) in the margins of the window.

You can jump between marks using the items in the Edit > Navigate menu. It's most convenient to use the keyboard shortcuts for those menu items, such as <kbd>⌘↑</kbd> for Jump to Previous Mark. If you hold down the Shift key, that changes to Select to Previous Mark. These can make it easier to find the beginning of command output.